# How I can get correctly return value from HoughCircles

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, computer-vision

I was clone [this](https://github.com/harshablast/Analog-Clock-Reader) project from GitHub but it doesn't working now. I don't yet know the cause of HoughCircles opencv (cv2) function return None.

Can anyone help me understand HoughCircles and solve this problem? Thank you.

```
img = cv2.imread('download.png', 1)
#img=cv2.resize(img,None,fx=2, fy=2, interpolation = cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
img_grayscale=cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
img_inverse=cv2.bitwise_not(img_grayscale)

#Circle Detection Part
circles = cv2.HoughCircles(img_inverse,cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT,1,20,param1=50,param2=200,minRadius=0,maxRadius=0)
circles = np.uint16(np.around(circles))
```

[image: Error]

Comment: Check this solution out to understand Hough circles better https://stackoverflow.com/a/67768649/10333818. Your parameters are messed up.

Answer (score 1):

If the circle is None that means your image didn't return any circle present in it. also, upload img for better understanding.
for this error you can do this

```
if circle is not None:
    circles = np.uint16(np.around(circles))
```